# TSQL string concatenation is not working within WHILE loop?

Tags: t-sql, string

Code bellow is not working, any ideas why?

```
declare @Counter int
set @Counter = 0
declare @ConcText nvarchar(1000)

while @Counter < 5
begin
    --set @ConcText = @ConcText + cast(@Counter as nvarchar(10)) + N' counter,'
    --set @ConcText = @ConcText + convert(nvarchar(10), @Counter) + N' counter,'
    set @ConcText = @ConcText + N' counter,'
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end
print @ConcText --<-- this is null, why  ??
```

Comment: Define "not working" What is is spitting out. What should it be spitting out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [MSDN: + (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx):

> Just like arithmetic operations that
>   are performed on null values, when a
>   null value is added to a known value
>   the result is typically an unknown
>   value, a string concatenation
>   operation that is performed with a
>   null value should also produce a null
>   result.

So to get things work, it's a good practice to initiate varchar variables immediatly after declare:

```
DECLARE @ConcText NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @ConcText  = ''
```

Other way to handle NULL concat issue (in case you don't know if value is NULL or not) - ISNULL or COALESCE:

```
SET @ConcText = ISNULL(@ConcText, '') + N' counter,'
SET @ConcText = COALESCE(@ConcText, '') + N' counter,'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting @ConcText to anything at the start, therefore when you concatenate anything to NULL you get NULL.